# DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBox doesn't appear

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Before setting datagridview with EditMode: EditProgrammatical the ComboBox appeared as it should.

After settings the EditMode: EditProgrammatical it requires 2-3 clicks on the arrow for the selection items to appear.

```
private void suggestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var dict = getSuggestDict();
  var dataGridViewComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
  {
    DataSource = dict.Keys.ToList();
  };

  dataGridView[selectedColumn, selectedRow] = dataGridViewComboBoxCell;
}
```

The function simplified a bit to avoid unnecessary complications.

Comment: dataGridView.Invalidate(); call this method after your column is updated

Comment: In what event or at what stage you set EditMode: EditProgrammatical. at design time?

Comment: @Munawar It is set in the whole duration of the execution.

Comment: @BaskarJohn Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable editing and set the focus to in question cell to make combo dropdown to open in single click.

```
 private void suggestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dict = getSuggestDict();
            var dataGridViewComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
            {
                DataSource = dict.Keys.ToList()
            };


            dataGridView[selectedColumn, selectedRow] = dataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedColumn];
            dataGridView.BeginEdit(false);
        }
```

**Edited:** Moved setting current cell and enabling edit mode at the start of button click event handler to ensure its in edit mode when replacing combobox contents.

```
private void suggestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedColumn];
   dataGridView.BeginEdit(true);

     var dict = getSuggestDict();
     var dataGridViewComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
     {
        DataSource = dict.Keys.ToList()
     };


dataGridView[selectedColumn, selectedRow] = dataGridViewComboBoxCell;

}
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly, but for some reason on the second click the dataGridView.BeginEdit(false) throws NullReferenceException, Do you know what causing this?

Comment: Do you mean on second click on suggestButton button OR on second click on DagaGridView Combobox cell?

Comment: I added to the beginning of the suggestButton_Click dataGridView.BeginEdit(true) and it stopped crashing, If you would like to edit your code that I will accept your answer.

Comment: Your code flow was not clear so, I put it at the end to ensure that rows/cell exists at that stage but have edited it per your above comments.

Comment: Just putting BeginEdit(true) at the start of your current code was perfect, but never mind that :)